# Can I broaden a patent while it is tested to work with specific conditions and environment?

Tags: patentability, claims

Suppose that I am going to file a patent about defect detection of a specific equipment based on machine vision (even its technology belongs to X company)

I implemented the system and it works for that equipment, now:

- Should I just claim about that specific equipment because my system is designed to work for it (should I then mention the manufacturer of the equipment or just describe it?), OR
- I can broaden my claim to any similar equipment from any other company (even if the method needs changes or refinements and adjustments)

In general, what they look, the implementation and the exact context and equipments or an abstract solution for something?

Comment: You should seek such legal advise from a registered patent agent or attorney.

Comment: @EntropyWins I asked it in general (I modified it though)